# A real polynomial of degree more than or equal to 3 is reducible, but does it necessarily have a real zero?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ideals, irreducible-polynomials, maximal-and-prime-ideals

[Takumi Murayama](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~b01902113/artin-sols.pdf) says "Every polynomial in $\mathbb R[x]$ of degree at least 3 has a real root, and therefore is not irreducible". I think I understand why it is [not irreducible](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1289649/show-that-a-real-polynomial-of-degree-more-than-or-equal-to-3-is-reducible), but what's the real root of $f(x)=(x^2+1)(x^2+2)$?

If he is right, then why?

If it is wrong, then what is probably meant? I think this has something to do with complex roots in pairs.

Comment: I believe the writer intended to add that the degree was odd.  Otherwise, the claim is false for the reason you report.  There are polynomials of arbitrarily high even degree with no root, $p_n(x)=(x^2+1)^n$ has degree $2n$ and has no real root, for example.

Comment: Yes, lulu is right; see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/689575/proof-that-every-polynomial-of-odd-degree-has-one-real-root).

Comment: The link from Murayama you attach is extremely long.  On what page does that quote appear?

Comment: The author's claim (on p. 39) is wrong.  What he meant is that every polynomial of degree three or more has irreducible factors which are at most quadratic: "*So, every maximal ideal is of the form (f) for f a linear polynomial or an irreducible quadratic polynomial.*"

Comment: @MichaelHoppe I thought something like that. Why don't you post as an answer? Thank you!

Comment: @JackBauer Well, in my opinion a comment is sufficient.

Comment: @lulu p. 39 last paragraph

Comment: @TakumiMurayama Then I'll just cite the solution as anonymous source? Thank you for your solutions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments

> The author's claim (on p. 39) is wrong. What he meant is that every polynomial of degree three or more has irreducible factors which are at most quadratic: "So, every maximal ideal is of the form (f) for f a linear polynomial or an irreducible quadratic polynomial." – Michael Hoppe Dec 22 at 12:09